# Calculated field in Access form that shows used amount out of total amount

Tags: ms-access

I have two tables in an Access 2010 Database: one table shows all the meetings done in a month and the other shows the receipts that are related to each topic discussed in the meeting.

I need a way to calculate the sum of al the receipts in one table related to a certain topic, in order to put it as used amount out of total of the meetings table.

Thank you very much for your attention and help!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the DSum-Function (or maybe DCount), they should be the easiest way to achive the desired result.

Example:

```
SELECT  MeetingId, 
        TotalValue,
        DSUM("ReceiptValue","tblReceipt", "MeetingId=" & [MeetingId]) AS UsedValue
FROM tblMeeting
```

Adapt table and field names as necessary.